# Needs to Change the field value of quantity and salesprice in opportunity product

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product

Can any one help me out on this?

Basically we have an option to add the products in opportunity.Similarly we do have an option to EDIT ALL product to change the value of fields such as Quantity,Sales Price ,List Price etc.

But its weird in product there are many products related.when i click on EDIT ALL …all the product has an option …but for the product where i want to change…does not give an option.

Please find the attached Screen :
[image]

In the above Screen you could see the Two products listed where the First product  it shows as read only ,doesnot have an option to change the field value...but i would like to change the value of Quantity and sales price.The Second product has an edit option to change the values.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to edit the Opp product from standard Opp Product edit page?

Comment: What is the url for the edit all page?

Comment: @SantanuHalder : We have Custom products ...it has an option to edit the VAlues of the field quantity and salesprice etc.except the product for which i would like to update.

Comment: @Eric :The Url of the Edit Page i get is :https://cs51.salesforce.com/oppitm/multilineitem.jsp?oppId=0064B000002UjfQ&retURL=%2F0064B000002UjfQ

Comment: Your URL seems to be the one with standard Opp Products. What do you mean by Custom Products?

Comment: @Eric:In the given below link ...we can change only the Quantity field...we dont have an option to change the value of Sales price.How does this sales price plays a role.For the first time the list price is taken as the sales price ...but from the second updates how is the sales price getting calculated.

Comment: Confused. In your picture in the question you cannot change qty or sales price of the first item

Comment: @Eric:I need to change both the values.

Comment: Does it have a schedule

Comment: @Eric:Yes.In that Reschedule we have only Quatity field to edit and the Salesprice field does not appears.

Comment: Then read my answer below as it applies to you

Answer (score 1):

It most likely has a schedule:

> **If an Opportunity Product has a schedule, the Quantity and Sales Price
>   standard fields behave as roll-up summary fields and cannot be edited.**
>   Additionally, these fields cannot be updated via the API.
>
> To adjust the values in the Quantity or Sales Price fields, we can
>   either delete or modify the product's schedule.  To edit the schedule,
>   open the opportunity product detail page and use the "Edit", "Delete",
>   or "Re-Establish" buttons located in the Schedule section within the
>   bottom-half of the page.
>
> If you do not see the "Schedule" Related List on the Opportunity
>   Product Page, be sure that Scheduling is enabled for the org, the
>   Product, and that the Related List is on the Page Layout.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187507&language=en_US